# Calculation of working time based on system uptime

Tags: linux, script, console

I know several tools that allow tracking time spend on different tasks / projects.

Is there any existing tool for very very simplified work-time-tracking.

Scenario:

I am an employee, come to the office, switch on my laptop directly. I have mostly around 1 hr lunchtime, but sometimes less, sometimes more.

At around 18:00 I want to type one command in the console (or simple GUI would also be okay of course) that tells me:

"1 hour overworked. Go home now! (came at 8:00, 1 hour standard lunch-break)."

Maybe there could be some parameter

mytool -lunch 2

"0 hour's left. Go home now! (came at 8:00, 2 hour lunch-break)."

Is there anything simple like that already?

Should run on Linux, COmmandline, maybe just a bash or python script.

EDIT: Solution by Akira - thanks!

```
$ mytool 2 | figlet
               _                            
  __ _  ___   | |__   ___  _ __ ___   ___   
 / _` |/ _ \  | '_ \ / _ \| '_ ` _ \ / _ \  
| (_| | (_) | | | | | (_) | | | | | |  __/_ 
 \__, |\___/  |_| |_|\___/|_| |_| |_|\___(_)
 |___/                                      
                        _              __________  __   
  _____   _____ _ __ __| |_   _  ___  |___ /___ / / /_  
 / _ \ \ / / _ \ '__/ _` | | | |/ _ \   |_ \ |_ \| '_ \ 
| (_) \ V /  __/ | | (_| | |_| |  __/  ___) |__) | (_) |
 \___/ \_/ \___|_|  \__,_|\__,_|\___| |____/____/ \___/ 

                              _       
 ___  ___  ___ ___  _ __   __| |___   
/ __|/ _ \/ __/ _ \| '_ \ / _` / __|  
\__ \  __/ (_| (_) | | | | (_| \__ \_ 
|___/\___|\___\___/|_| |_|\__,_|___(_)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash (put to your `~/.bashrc`):

```
function mytool() {

    # ${1-0} means: take the first argument or assume 0 if 
    # no argument was given

    MAX="$(( (8 + ${1-0}) * 3600))" # $1 carries additional hours
    UP=`cat /proc/uptime | sed 's/\..*//'`

    if (( $UP > $MAX ))
    then
        echo "go home. overdue $(( $UP - $MAX )) seconds."
    fi
}
```

just call it like `mytool 2`.

or .. awk (just for the fun of it):

```
awk -v lunch=2 'BEGIN { max=(8 + lunch) * 3600;} { if ($1 > $max) print "overdue " ($1 - max) / 3600.0 " hours"; }' /proc/uptime
```

Comment: Hey this is not stack overflow :-) Thanks for the great answer! Seems to work.